# Javascript .replace() with RegEx causes browser to hang/crash

Tags: javascript, html, regex, performance, freeze

My goal it to loop through a set of given elements, and replace there inner HTML with a linkifying Regex so I can convert HTML text in the form of `http://*.*/*` into `<a href="http://*.*/*" target="_blank">http://*.*/*</a>`

So I'm running a bit of vanilla javascript:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('title').length; i++) {
    var title = document.getElementsByClassName('title')[i]
    title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a target='_blank' href='$1'>$1</a>")
}
```

Here's just the RegExp I'm using:

`/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig`

So, why on earth would this loop cause the browser to hang? The loop is over text no longer than 256 characters and there are usually between 5 and 30 `.title` elements, definitely not the levels of data that would crash/hang a browser. I've only experienced it in Chrome/Safari, unsure if it happens in Firefox/Opera or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing results.

```
var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
// querySelectorAll is supported in slightly more browsers than getElementsByClassName
var l = titles.length, i, title;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    title = titles[i];
    title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.replace(/..../,'....');
}
```

If the hanging continues, it's probably because the regex is matching stuff you've already replaced. Try adding a negative lookahead to ensure there is no single quote immediately after the URL you are matching. `(?=!')`

Comment: Could you show some example code related to the note on the negative lookahead? Thanks for your answer, seems quite informed!

Comment: Is this how I would add the negative lookahead?

/(?=!')(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig

Comment: The lookahead goes at the end.

Comment: I was wrong, it did not in fact go away. Could you show me what the js regex would look like with the negative lookahead? Thanks!